# How can I do stemming on Arabic text using R?

Tags: r, arabic, stemming

How can I do stemming (getting the root of a word) on Arabic Text that consists of 10000 sentences using R ?
for example a word like  "اعلاميون" gives "علم"
                     and " حركات" gives " حرك "

Answer (score 0):

```
arabic <- c("اعلاميون")
arabic_document <- VCorpus(VectorSource(arabic))
arabic_stem <- tm_map(arabic_document, stemDocument, language = 'arabic')
```

Would usually work however the `tm` package does not suport Arabic as far as I can tell.

Try some variation of;

```
library(arabicStemR)

arabic <- tm_map(arabic_document, content_transformer(stem))
```

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arabicStemR/arabicStemR.pdf